# Using 2 apple watch with same iphone, calories add up?

Tags: iphone, apple-watch

I have a family member using an Apple watch, I would like to get another Apple watch and have them both to the same iPhone.  I want the calories from both Apple watch to add up in health app e.g. family member burned 300 calories and I burned 500 calories today then I want to see 800 calories.

I know you can swap each of the watches to active so when I swap each watch to active at the end of the day will it add up both calories from individual watches?

Comment: Have you tested both watches being on the same Apple ID?

Comment: I only have 1 watch right now.

Comment: So do I, but I don't need 2 and you do so you can test.

Comment: Add up in the watch or on the iPhone?